# On Windows, how can I protect arguments to shell scripts using Python 2.7 subprocess?

Tags: python, windows, shell, subprocess

Consider for example the following Python code:

```
subprocess.call([r'.\tst.bat', '"1|2"'])
```

Here I've put double quotes around the argument to tst.bat, in order to protect '|' from the shell since tst.bat will ultimately be run via the Windows shell. However, if there are double quotes in arguments, subprocess in Python 2.7 escapes them. The result is that tst.bat receives this argument: \"1|2\".

How can I escape the argument "1|2" so that it's passed untransformed to tst.bat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subprocess module on Windows in case of a list of arguments given to the `call` method [transforms](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/026ee0057e2d/Lib/subprocess.py#l907) this list into a string using [`list2cmdline`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/026ee0057e2d/Lib/subprocess.py#l579) function. In the docstring of this function one can read:

> 3) A double quotation mark preceded by a backslash is interpreted as a
>   literal double quotation mark.

According to this the solution of your problem should look like this

```
subprocess.call([r'.\tst.bat', r'\"1|2\"'])
```

However it seems like there's a mismatch between documentation and implementation of `list2cmdline` function;

```
Python 2.7.4 (default, Apr  6 2013, 19:55:15) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import subprocess
>>> print subprocess.list2cmdline([r'\"1|2\"'])
\\\"1|2\\\"
```

The same behavior is in Python 3.3.1.
I raised a bug at http://bugs.python.org/issue18649

**UPDATE**

It turns out I was confused by very misleading docstring of `list2cmdline` function - see http://bugs.python.org/issue18649 for details.

The sequence of arguments passed to `subprocess.call` is translated by `list2cmdline` function which is concerned only with the quoting mechanism used by MS C runtime and not by quoting mechanism used by cmd.exe. This makes passing arguments - which are later to be interpreted by cmd.exe - to `subprocess.call` as a list either very awkward or impossible.

There's one more chance to get it working in this case, though. `list2cmdline` double quotes every argument with a space or tab inside. If having a space at the end of your argument does not break the batch file you can add it at the end forcing double quoting as you wanted.

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> print subprocess.list2cmdline(['1|2 '])
"1|2 "
```

Comment: Having read the list2cmdline docstring now, it seems to me that list2cmdline produces a string that the MS C runtime can use to launch a process. For example, a double quote preceeded by a backslash (`\"`) must be preserved as is, so that it can be passed on to the MS C runtime (which in turn parses it as a literal double quote).

Comment: @aknuds1 *Having read the list2cmdline docstring now, it seems to me that list2cmdline produces a string that the MS C runtime can use to launch a process* Correct. *(...) a double quote preceeded by a backslash (`\"`) must be preserved (...)* Not really. The backslash has to be escaped with another backslash and the double quotation mark has to escaped with a backslash, too. This way when MS C runtime will get `\\\"` as input string it will transform this back to the original `\"` sequence.

Comment: Not sure if I follow you, what I meant is that the C runtime should receive a `\"` via its commandline parameter, which it proceeds to parse as a `"`.

Comment: Right. The problem is in this case it's not C runtime that gets to interpret commadline string but cmd.exe. We would like to pass `"` to cmd.exe but we can't because a) every `"` character is being quoted by list2cmdline function b) there's no combination of other escape sequences which would result in list2cmdline to output plain `"` character which we want to get at the end (so that it would subsequently be passed to cmd.exe).

Comment: That was my understanding too regarding cmd.exe :)

Answer (score 0):

This (or a similar problem) has been reported as a bug.

References:

- http://bugs.python.org/issue2304
- http://bugs.python.org/issue11139
- http://bugs.python.org/issue8972

Comment: http://bugs.python.org/issue11139 is mine, and it's not quite the same issue, although definitely related :) The other bugs also don't touch directly on this issue.

Comment: @aknuds1 Actually shypike's [comment](http://bugs.python.org/issue8972#msg107713) in issue 8972 talks directly about the problem you observe - *An element like `r'"foo"'` is translated to `r'\"foo\"'`. This is incorrect because cmd.exe cannot handle this.*

Comment: @PiotrDobrogost Has it become clear why list2cmdline escapes double quotes in the first place? I can't see from its docstring that it's supposed to.

Comment: @aknuds1 That's because `list2cmdline` produces string which later will be processed by MS C runtime and the rules in the docstring describe behavior of this runtime and not behavior of `list2cmdline` function. Yes, this is highly confusing - see my comment at http://bugs.python.org/issue18649#msg194405

Comment: @PiotrDobrogost I realize list2cmdline protects double quotes from the runtime, but I'm wondering if it's a bad thing when launching a shell, considering that the shell receives escaped double quotes (as you can see from my original question).

Comment: @aknuds1 Yes, this does not play well with shell. There should be a special function/mode taking into account cmd.exe quoting mechanism as was concluded in different issues regarding subprocess on Windows, yours http://bugs.python.org/issue11139 among them.